# Assign command ctrl+z/ctrl+y to button?

Tags: javascript, html

I m creating one application using ASP>NET MVC,JavaScript,JQuery,KendoUI.
Is it possible to assign command <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to button in HTML/HTML5 ?
If yes then how ?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to be using JavaScript to detect key presses.

Since you are already using jQuery in your application, consider the following:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if ( e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122 ) {
      myCtrlZFunction();
  } 
  else if( e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 121 ) {
      myCtrlYFunction();
  }
});
```

***e*** in the keydown's closure argument is the number code for the key depressed. The code for z is 122, the code for y 121.

All you really need to do then is to create your myCtrlZFunction() and myCtrlYFunction()

You can see the different keycode values on: http://expandinghead.net/keycode.html

Comment: i want to execute this commands on single button press on editor.you show how to handle Ctrl+z/y but i want to perform this action on single button.

Comment: Which button? And if you want to use a 'single button' why did you specify the use of `ctrl` + `z`/`ctrl` + `y` in your question?

Comment: i mean ctrl+y in one separate button and ctrl+z in another separate button.

Comment: i don't want to detect but i want to perform same action like ctrl+z and ctrl+y on button click.like i want to give undo and redo button for text area.on press of this button i want to undo and redo content of text area.

Comment: You could use the same functions for both the key clicks and the buttons. Or, you could simulate a click on the button via jQuery: $("#button").click();

Answer (score 2):

Use this, it works fine on me:

```
function execFnct() {
    document.execCommand("undo", false, null);
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea style="width: 499px; height: 230px; border: 1px solid red;"></textarea>
<div style="width: 499px; height: 230px; border: 1px solid red;" contentEditable="true"></div>
<input type="button" onmouseup="execFnct()"/>
```

The `execCommand` function in this case works with `textarea` or any `contentEditable` element.

Answer (score 0):

This works PERFECT as Redo and Undo buttons:

**style CSS:**

```
.textId { width: 499px; height: 230px; border: 1px solid red; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function Undo() { document.execCommand("undo", false, null); }
function Redo() { document.execCommand("redo", false, null); }
```

**HTML codes**

```
<textarea class="textId"></textarea>
<div class="textId" contentEditable="true"></div>
<input type="button" onmouseup="Undo()"/ value="Undo">
<input type="button" onmouseup="Redo()"/ value="Redo">
```

**Complete EXAMPLE:**

```
<html><head></head>

<style>.textId { width: 499px; height: 230px; border: 1px solid red; }</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
function Undo() { document.execCommand("undo", false, null); }
function Redo() { document.execCommand("redo", false, null); }
</script>

<body>

<textarea class="textId"></textarea>
<div class="textId" contentEditable="true"></div>
<input type="button" onmouseup="Undo()"/ value="Undo">
<input type="button" onmouseup="Redo()"/ value="Redo">

</body></html>
```

**PS:** It may not call CTRL+Z and CTRL+Y but it does the redo and undo commands. Personally I am still trying to find out how to get the CTRL+V command in a button. If you do, please inform me. But Anyway this solution is the only working solution I found for CTRL+Z and CTRL+Y buttons yet only for a div box not a textarea box :( .